# Why redirecting output sometimes produces an empty file?

Tags: shell, pipe, io-redirection

The power of shell pipeline is so great that sometimes fails me.

#### Example

**Just as an** example, the pipeline

```
echo abc > file.txt
cat file.txt | sed 's/a/1/' > file.txt
```

gives me an empty `file.txt`. Realizing that the shell probably calls `>` first, I made a change:

```
echo abc > file.txt
{cat file.txt | sed 's/a/1/'} > file.txt
```

Again it surprises me by another empty file `file.txt`. An ugly way that finally works is

```
echo abc > file.txt
echo $(cat file.txt | sed 's/a/1') > file.txt
```

which forces the shell to run a subshell first, and then redirect.

#### Question

While I'm aware of better practice of `sed`, which allows you to get rid of `echo`, `cat`, `grep`.. etc, what I am curious about here is to learn shell's grammar completely. **This questions is not about how to fix the particular problem above.**

Q1(EDIT: off-topic) Is there a good resource for me to learn the grammar?

I'm afraid that different shells could have different grammars, so

**Q2** Can I make shell verbose, and see clearly what it is doing every completely every single time I run a command?

Q3(EDIT: off-topic) Any other advice on good practices? Thank you!

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/443154 may be helpful

Comment: Q1 & Q3 are off-topic for U&L; please edit your question down to Q2 only. Thank you!

Comment: The easiest way to enable "verbose" is to turn on the trace flag: `bash -x script.sh` or in an interactive shell `set -x`

Comment: Good resources to learn the grammar: not really. In my experience, the best way is to practice practice practice, ask questions, and follow the [tag:shell] tag here and on stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you.. @SergiyKolodyazhnyy but that was just an example to illustrate my situation: I not only want to solve this problem, but also want to avoid similar problems in the future.

Comment: You could also use `exec 3<file.txt; rm file.txt; sed 's/a/1/' <&3 >file.txt` (At least with `bash`. Not 100% sure about `sh`.) But of course, using `sed`'s `-i` option is better.

Comment: @ikegami That's a pretty good solution. Can you post that to the linked question please ? Let me know once you do

Comment: @Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy, Done, with an explanation. And it does appear to work in `sh`. (Well, I tested with `dash`, which I believe is suppose to be a compliant implementation of `sh`?)

Comment: @ikegami Yes, on Ubuntu/Debian-based OSs `/bin/sh` is dash, but it can differ by distro. But theoretically any POSIX-compliant version of `/bin/sh`  have `exec` ( [listed in built-in spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/idx/sbi.html) )

Comment: Same question on Stack Overflow: [ubuntu - Why doesnt "tail" work to truncate log files? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759448/why-doesnt-tail-work-to-truncate-log-files)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have successfully found one of the things you should not do :-)
Never redirect to the file you are working on!

A1: a good resource to learn shell grammar would be the [absolute bash scripting guide](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/), IMO

A2: For bash-scripts, you can use `set +x` for more verbose output, but I don't know how to achieve the same at a 'run things at the prompt'-level.

A3: Add `[solved]` to your search-terms.  Finds you the solution to your problem instead of more of the problem you already know.

Comment: .. Having `set +x`, it still doesn't hint me why there's a problem. I guess I should just make friend with shell(s), and know all of its (their) perks.

Answer (score 19):

Consider [3.1.1 Shell Operation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Operation), particularly the order in which things are done:

- redirections are processed **before** the command is actually executed, but
- expansions are processed before redirections.

This means that for `cat file > file`, the output redirection (which truncates the file) occurs before `cat` is spawned, and `cat` now has an empty file to work with.

But `echo "$(cat file)" > file` does what you expect because the [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) is a [Shell Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions), and that happens before redirections.

The typical advice is to do

```bsh
cat file > tmpfile && mv tmpfile file
```

You can use [`mktemp`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/mktemp.1.html) here.

Or install the `moreutils` package and use [`sponge`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/sponge.1.html)

```bsh
cat file | sponge file
```

---

Although to address the specific command you're using, replace

```
cat file.txt | sed 's/a/1/' > file.txt
```

with (assuming GNU sed)

```
sed -i 's/a/1/' file.txt
```

Comment: `echo` does what you expect, if you expect the wildly different behaviors `echo` can have (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803). The shortest example would be for `file` to contain only the string `-n`.

Answer (score 0):

One way of solving the problem is learning exactly what order redirections, expansions, subshells etc happen so that you can catch this type of error before it happens.

I do not recommend this.  You will still mess up occasionally and the cost can be lost data.

It is better to *not* trust your ability to keep all this straight and write more idiot-proof code.  **We are all idiots sometimes.**

So

```
cp file.txt file.txt.old
cat file.txt.old | sed 's/a/1/' > file.txt
```

This is simpler in that there is no dependencies on order of events, other than line 1 happening before line 2.

As an added benefit it guards against *other* errors, when you shouldn't have run this script at all.

The cost of this practice is that you will have `.old` files laying around everywhere.  This is an insurance premium you will be glad you paid the day you need it.  Disk is cheap.

Comment: You _don't_ recommend learning the order of evaluation?

Comment: @Kusalananda Well, mostly I recommend *not depending* on that knowledge.  But feel free to learn it if you want to.

Comment: Well, I guess @StigHemmer just recommends to backup always. Thanks for reminding :)